# What's the advantages of usb 3.0 compliant thumbdrive that doesn't have USB 3.0 speed performance?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, usb-3, usb-2

I just learned that there are USB 3.0 compliant thumbdrives in the market that only support up to the maximum speed of USB 2.0 (nothing to do with using USB 3.0 device on USB 2.0 port here) and they are marketed as "entry level" in USB 3.0 product range by their manufacturer. So I'm wondering given this performance limitation despite being USB 3.0, is there any advantage that this kind of thumbdrive has over a standard USB 2.0 thumbdrive?

Comment: Sounds like they are saying it is compatible with USB 3.0 but only USB 2.0 maybe? Can you link to one of the thumbdrives that is like this?

Comment: They actually work on USB 3.0 ports. Just went through this misery with an HP Envy. I **Envy** people who have USB ports that **just work**. That touted backwards compatibility is nice when it's built in to the device you're connecting to those blue-plastic wonders, lotta shillin' going on, but USB 3.0 hubs just ain't cutting it and you're kind of stuck as all 4 are SS. You will probably have to re-buy 50% of your USB peripherals.

Comment: @cojomojo [Kingston DT100G3](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820239626) Read the review section